# Is it possible to list all files starting with a letter, but not directories?

Tags: bash, shell

I need for my home assignment somehow to get a list of all the files starting with the letter *F*, I know of the command:

```
ls F*
```

But it also gives me directories, is it possible to only show actual files?

Answer (score 4):

POSIXly:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type f -name 'F*'
```

With `zsh`:

```
print -rl -- F*(.)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure - using [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) (which does not sort names as `ls` does, so I added that):

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -name 'F*' |sort |xargs ls -l {} \;
```

or (if you want only the names)

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -name 'F*' |sort
```

The `-maxdepth` option is not in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), but since you tagged this with `bash`, we can make some assumptions.  For instance, it works with [OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) (the other platform where people generally use `bash`).

In any case, left to itself, `find` will show files in subdirectories, which is something that `ls` will *not* do without adding a [`-R`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html) option.

One issue with `find` is that its output may include filenames with nonprinting characters (blanks, etc).  Both Linux and OSX `find` provide an *extension* (not in POSIX) called `-print0`, which works with [`xargs`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xargs.1.html) complementary extension `-0`.  So you *could* do this:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -print0 -name 'F*'  |sort -z |xargs -0 ls -l {} \;
```

or (if you want to give up the sorting feature), you could use straight POSIX:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -name 'F*' -exec ls -l {} +
```

Sorting is mainly an issue when you want a detailed listing, but the POSIX **`+`** would not be helpful if you want a sorted list, since (still legal) newlines in the list of names would interfere with sorting.

[@cuonglm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/38906/cuonglm) points out that POSIX has the `-prune` option, which says:

> **`-prune`**
>   The primary shall always evaluate as true; it shall cause find not to descend the current pathname if it is a directory.

and if you are using "." for the argument of `find` (as done here), then there is no need of the `-maxdepth` option.  True enough, but if we pursue the analogy to `ls` further, then "." is the equivalent of `ls -a`, while strictly matching OP's question would drop the "-a" option and the argument to `find` could be "*".  However (as reminded by [@cuonglm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/38906/cuonglm)), `-prune` is only useful for *directories*, and `find * -prune` would match directory contents.

One could also use a shell wildcard expansion, e.g.,

```
for n in F*;do [ -f "$n" ] && echo "$n"; done
```

which is (probably) preferable to `ls F*` since it does not convert nonprinting characters into question marks, wildcard expansion in either case runs into command-length restrictions.

Ultimately, the answer depends on whether OP wants a *listing* or a *list* of names.  But in either case, `ls` by itself cannot do the job.

Comment: `-maxdepth` is not POSIX

Comment: `-type f` only selects regular files and not the other types of non-directories (the OP's question is unclear though since directories are just one of many types of files). Use `! -type d` for non-directories. `[ -f "$n" ]` returns true for regular files and symlinks to regular files. `[ ! -d "$n" ] || [ -L "$n" ]` for non-directories.

Answer (score 1):

I could use the find command:

```
find ./ -name "F*" -type f
```

*-type f* means you want regular files only.

Comment: This will list files in subdirectory, which glob `F*` didn't.

Comment: Yes that's right.